# Sublime 3: Subl not working

Tags: osx-mavericks, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Before today I had Sublime 2 and 3 on my computer. When I ran the subl command in the terminal it would always open Sublime 2, which I never use anymore. Therefore I got rid of Sublime 2. Now my subl command does not work at all. All I get is subl command not found.

I understand that I have to put a subl binary file into my bin folder. I was just wondering what might be the best way to go about doing that. Any insight on this particular instance would help.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly after I posted this question I found the answer. The issue was that because the subl file in my bin or binary folder was tied to Sublime 2, when I uninstalled Sublime 2 it also uninstalled that binary.

All I did was copy the subl file from Sublime 3 into the bin or binary folder. I did have use the terminal in order to get down to the bin folder. Once I opened both folders with the terminal I just copied the subl binary from Sublime 3 to my binary folder.

Answer (score 0):

According to [their website](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html):

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

(The command is almost identical to [the one for version 2](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html).)

If you have a fresh install of OS X, this will probably fail for you. First, create a `~/bin` directory under your home and add it to your path. This will vary by your shell, but if you use bash..

```
mkdir ~/bin
echo "export PATH=$PATH:~/bin" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then you should be able to run the `ln` command and `subl` to your hearts content.

As a side note, a simplified version of this can be accomplished with the `open` command for any app. Try `open -a TextEdit hello.txt` for similar effect. I've aliased this for a hex editor that didn't offer a CLI launcher like `subl`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (it worked for me)

```
alias subl="'/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'"

alias nano="subl"

export EDITOR="subl"
```